# Swift custom rgb color not shown

Tags: ios, swift, button, cell, rgb

So i use a custom color from https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html for button title in cell. But somehow some colors are not set like the silver color RGB((192,192,192), it just show white color for the cell button label.

I set button title color using the following syntax:

```
cell.viewAllButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 192, green: 192, blue: 192, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
```

For other colors, it set the button label successfully.

Comment: Duh...  UIColor(red: 192/255.0, green: 192/255.0, blue: 192/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: @ElTomato I don't understand why it worked for other colors, could you tell me?

Comment: @IskandarH values over 1 get capped to 1. So for example, `UIColor(red: 100, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)` would resolve to `UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)` (which is `red`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work

```
cell.viewAllButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
```